How to kill Java Threads Running on containers?
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class RestApi {
    HashMap<String,Thread> threadsWithName = new HashMap();

    @GetMapping("/{someId}")
    public String getThreadName(@PathVariable(value = "someId") final String id) {
        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        String threadName = thread.getName();
        threadsWithName.put(id,thread);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            threadsWithName.remove(id);
        }
        threadsWithName.remove(id);
        return threadName + " has executed";
    }

    @GetMapping("/runningThreads")
    public ArrayList runningThreads(){
        ArrayList threadnames = new ArrayList();
        for(Map.Entry thread:threadsWithName.entrySet()){
            threadnames.add(thread.getKey());
        }
        return threadnames;
    }

    @GetMapping("/killThreadWithId/{someId}")
    public String killThreadWithId(@PathVariable(value = "someId") final String id){
        Thread thread = threadsWithName.get(id);
        String getName = thread.getName();
        thread.interrupt();
        threadsWithName.remove(id);
        return getName + " killed active count : "+ Thread.activeCount();
    }

    @GetMapping("/activecount")
    public int killThreadWithId(){
        return Thread.activeCount();
    }
}


I want to implement a program through which we can kill time consuming threads :-

I am keeping Thread objects in a HashMap but I have never seen it being done by anyone else so it it fine?
How to implement this functionality when my app is running on many containers because I believe each container will have separate threads.
Any suggestions to have a common place(Cache,database, etc) to keep the data in threadsWithName. Thanks!!



In theory, I don't see why not.  2) I think you have already done that.  Just make an appropriate REST call (i.e. "/killthreadswithid/...") to the container where the thread is running. 3) Any of those ideas would work.


But if you are literally asking how to kill (destroy), stop or pause uncooperative threads (that don't respond to interrupt) that is not possible.  Or at least, not reliably or portably.

3a) Maybe a better way is to use structured names for the threads; e.g. "@".  That way you don't need to maintain a distributed data structure / database of all thread names.

@StephenC The questions is in this case how to know which thread is running on which container when we need to kill them.

I can think of three ways: 1) use a database, cache, whatever that maps thread names to containers, 2) use structured names as per my comment above, 3) send the "/killthreadswithid/..." request to all containers' APIs.
